# Would this violate any copyright issues?

Tags: copyright, research, computer-vision

I am currently publishing a paper on skin detection. However, I need to find the appropriate histogram bin size for each colorspace. I recently came upon a paper that published what it found to be the ideal bin size. The paper can be found at: http://www.inf.pucrs.br/~pinho/CG/Trabalhos/DetectaPele/Artigos/OPTIMUM%20COLOR%20SPACES%20FOR%20SKIN%20DETECTION.pdf. I am specifically talking about Table 1. If I cite the source, would it be okay for me to use data from the table?

Note that I cannot contact the author of the paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes using the data would be perfectly normal

But I'm not a lawyer, I'm only an academic talking about the etiquette of quoting results from another academic paper, I can't say anything about the copyright law in Azerbijan when applied to web apps by a Liberian shell company registered in the Cayman islands.

Comment: Your answer is a bit contradictory...
You said yes it does, but then followed it with its normal. Which one is it? :)

Comment: Sorry, made the answer clearer - I meant yes it would be perfectly normal